# Parse unix timestamp with decimal from float using time.Unix()?

Tags: go, time, floating-point, precision, unix-timestamp

This is pretty straightforward, but I couldn't find a response and figured that others might have the same question.

I have a Unix timestamp as a float, that includes a decimal value for fractions of seconds. What's the conversion factor to pass this float as two separate integers to the `time` package's `time.Unix(sec int64, nsec int64)` function, without losing the decimal precision?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
sec, dec := math.Modf(timeFloat);
time.Unix(int64(sec), int64(dec*(1e9)));
```

Comment: 10^9 is a binary XOR operation and not a power operator. Use 1000000000 or just 1e9 instead

Comment: Whoops! You're right, fixed. Thanks for the comment